# How does one test ESC key press to close window?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In our app there is a certain controller attached to a div, that listens to key press events an propagates it down to its children. In a webdriver test how do I raise an ESC event? I have tried

```
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
```

but it doesn't trigger the event.

If I find element by css, such as the div my handler is attached to, selenium doesn't allow sending ESC event to just any element such as divs, but only to specific input elements, and it gives the error.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus
>   element.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: You must first **find** your `div` element, **click** on it, and finally **send** keys.

Comment: Thanks Martinez. That did the trick: 
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("myclassname")))
        .click()
        .sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE)
        .perform();